# How increase ratio in current location blue circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mkmapview

The reason for this is that I'm getting information in a range of 5 km, therefore would denote that area I'm looking for.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: That blue circle indicates the uncertainty of the GPS signal. If the phone thinks GPS is weak, that circle will be bigger. If you want a circle of a certain size, add an `MKCircle` overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That blue circle indicates the device's position. A smaller circle indicates greater accuracy. Maybe you're looking for CLLocationManager.desiredAccuracy?

If you want your own circle on the map, you're gonna need to add a custom annotation by subclassing MKAnnotation & MKAnnotationView. Or an overlay would be able to do the same thing with MKOverlay and MKOverlayRenderer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, the `MKAnnotation` are not the problem. Only need increase the size of the blue circle